# jquery functions to get dynamic controls

Tags: jquery-selectors

I am added json object data and three buttons for every li tag in my webpage.
My requirement is , I want to get that dynamically added button . But i am not getting that button by using script below

```
$("but1").click(function(){
   alert("hi iam getting dynamic added button");
});
```

So please give me some suggession to acheive this.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#selector').live('click', function(){} )
```

Since they don't exist, you need to use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method for dynamic generated elements:

```
$("#but1").live('click', function(){
   alert("hi iam getting dynamic added button");
});
```

**live()**

> Description: Attach a handler to the
>   event for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now or in the
>   future.